# does a simple random walk eventually hit every point?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $M_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}X_k$ be a simple random walk starting at $0$, where $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

What is the probability the random walk hits the point $z\in\mathbb{Z}$?

I have a feeling that

$P(M_n\;\mathrm{eventually\; hits}\; z) =1$

Is this true and if so how can I prove it? or can you provide a reference please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $z \in {\mathbb Z}$, the random walk reaches $z$ infinitely many times with probability $1$.  See for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a proof that uses the theorem of martingale convergence, and I think it is a quick proof if you have some knowledge of martingales.

Let $T$ be the first time $n$ such that $M_n=z$. $T$ is a stopping time. WLOG $z\ge0$. $(M_n)_n$ is a martingale, and the stopped martingale $(M^T_n)_n$ is also a martingale. So $\mathbb{E}(M^T_n)=\mathbb{E}(M^T_0)=\mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$ for every $n$. But note that the positive part of $M^T_n$ is at most $z$. So $\mathbb{E}((M^T_n)^+)\le z$, which, together with the observation that $\mathbb{E}(M^T_n)=0$ leads to $\mathbb{E}(|M^T_n|)\le 2z$ for every $n$. Therefore, $(M^T_n)_n$ converges almost surely. But the nature of the random walk is such that unless $(M^T_n)_n$ stops at $z$, it will jump up and down and not converge. So $(M^T_n)_n$ converges to $z$ almost surely. In other words, the random walk eventually hits $z$ almost surely.